# Converting 9319106.045445956 in unknown coordinate system to WGS84?

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, wgs84

From some API I'm receiving latlng coordinates in a stranger format: `x: 9319106.045445956, y: 7020308.253131529`, I don't know what it is, but my map module works only with WGS84 coordinates: `lat: 53.2011871329117, lng: 83.71485471725465`

What is original coords system and how to convert these coordinates to WGS84?

Comment: Have you tried https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=identify+coordinate+system ?

Comment: The original coords are Web Mercator, EPSG:3857.